# How to find the most frequently repeated column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-order-by, sql-limit

```
ID  UserID LevelID
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   1       2
4   1       2
5   2       1
6   2       3
7   3       2
8   4       1
9   4       1
```

The query should return: LevelID: 1 (3 times) - the LevelID column that is most frequently repeated by different Users (UserID).

I have the following query:

```
SELECT LevelID, COUNT(LevelID) AS 'Occurrence' 
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
  (
    SELECT UserID, LevelID
    FROM SampleTable
  ) cv
) levels
GROUP BY LevelID
ORDER BY 'Occurrence'  DESC
```

Which returns:

```
LevelID Occurence
1        3      
2        2      
3        1
```

But it doesn't let me to add `LIMIT 1;` at the bottom to retrieve the first top row of the selection. What's wrong with the query?

Comment: count on select distinct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for these several levels of nesting. Consider using aggregation, `count(distinct ...)`, ordering the results and using a row-limiting clause to keep the top record only:

```
select top(1) levelID, count(distinct userID) cnt
from mytable
group by levelID
order by cnt desc
```

If you want to allow possible top ties, then use `top (1) with ties` instead of just `top (1)`.

Comment: This says: Incorrect syntax near desc. SELECT TOP 1 LevelID, COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) cnt FROM SampleTable GROUP BY cnt DESC I also tried with group by and order by separately but it says incorrect syntax. Why?

Comment: @Nikolai: sorry - fixed.